# Parsing Included Associations from JSON API response - Rails API, AMS, Vue.js SPA

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, json, vue.js, active-model-serializers

I have some data that in a tree/hierarchal model for (climbing) Areas, such that they relate via parent and child areas.

Using the JSON API adapter with my Active Model Serializer,

```
class AreaSerializer < ActiveModel::Serializer
  attributes :id, :name, :description, :location, :slug
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :parent
  has_many :children
end
```

I can return the Area with the parent and children included in my controller:

```
class AreasController < ApplicationController

  ...

  def show
    area = Area.friendly.find(params[:id])
    render json: area, include: [:children, :parent]
  end
end
```

and return exactly what's expected: The JSON response that has Area data, a relationships object that identifies a user_id/type, parent_id/type, children_id/type.  This is all being sent to a mutation in a Vuex store for a Vue SPA.

The **problem** is that everything is mixed up in the `included` member of the response.  I ultimately want easy access to the `parent "slug"` and store an array of `children` separately.

Yes, the response has the children and parent in there, but they are all of the same `type: "areas"`, and all together in one array.  There must be some reasonable way to parse this data in javascript, such that I can compare the `parent: data { id: "5" }` in the `relationships` member of the response to the `id` of one of the `included` array members

I understand that I can make this easier if I drop the JSON API spec and just use the default serializer, which will give me `parent` and `children` attributes directly in the response data.

Is there some way to parse these related objects in javascript into clearly defined arrays/objects of their own?  Maybe I should drop the JSON API specs for this one and just control my data output directly from the server?

I hope that makes sense; someone must have run into this before, but I couldn't find any examples...

Answer (score 0):

You can parsing a response object manually:

```
// User response from server:

const user = {
  "id": "1",
  "type": "users",
  "attributes": {
    "name": "John Doe"
  },
  "included": [
    {
      "id": "2",
      "type": "roles",
      "attributes": {
        "name": "Admin"
      }
    }
  ]
};

// Manually parsing a User response object:
user.id; // 1
user.attributes.name; // John Doe
user.included.filter(obj => obj.type === 'roles')[0].attributes.name; // Admin
```

Or, you can use JSONAPI Suite: https://jsonapi-suite.github.io/jsonapi_suite/js/home

Answer (score 0):

### first you should fix your serializer

your relation `has_many :children` it's wrong you should fix it with `has many :childrens`

because you has many childrens not children!!!

### second you can change include relations and change show defination

```
def show
  area = Area.friendly.find(params[:id])
  render jsonapi: area, include: %w(childrens, parent)
end
```

probably it's work!!!